# Check folder for new images and display them on Linux/RPi command line

Tags: image, cron, raspberry-pi3, display, fbi

My script downloads a new image from a web resource once per hour.
I want to display that image on a monitor connected to a raspberry pi.

What works:

- downloading an image via cron job every hour
- deleting any previous downloaded images from the downloads folder
- displaying the image from the downloads folder on boot

What doesn't work:

- updating the displayed image with the new one automatically when it changed or every hour

My `/etc/profile/` has this line added:

```
/home/pi/code/display/display-image.sh
```

Which executes the script on boot.

`display-image.sh` is just a two-liner:

```
killall fbi
fbi -noverbose -a /home/pi/code/display/images/*.png
```

which does work fine.

Now the problem I face is that I need `fbi` (or `fim` or `feh`, I tried them all) to check if the image in the downloads folder has been updated and therefore display the new one.

I see two options:

- a setting within fbi, fim or feh that checks for new files in a folder (which would be the best option, but I haven't found that option and it seems they all cache the file list on start)
- executing a cron job which kills fbi/fim/feh and restarts it

I tried the cron job (via `crontab -e`):
`*/6 * * * * DISPLAY=:0 /home/pi/code/display/display-image.sh`

But I must make an error here in some way, as the cron job doesn't succeed displaying the image. The output gives me `ioctl VT_GETSTATE: Inappropriate ioctl for device (not a linux console?)`, but I'm not sure if this is the problem or how to solve that.

How can I update my display with the newly downloaded image?

Comment: Have a read here https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/702521/400632